# Android Navigation Rail Headerview onclick not working

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to set onclicklistener on navigation railview but it doesn't work for me

**Java code**

```
 binding.navigationRail.getHeaderView().setClickable(true);
    binding.navigationRail.getHeaderView().setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Toast.makeText(this, "headerview", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    });
```

**Xml**

```
    <com.google.android.material.navigationrail.NavigationRailView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_rail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/floatbutton_add_product"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_rail_menu" />
```

Answer (score 0):

that's worked for me

```
        View header=binding.navigationRail.getHeaderView();
    FloatingActionButton FloatingActionButton=  header.findViewById(R.id.nav_rail_fab);
    FloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "headerview", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).